# Why I'm not using 100%?

Tags: java, performance, websphere, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm executing a long running batch process in IBM WebSphere Application Server v8.5.5.1, which is getting data from a ECM repository, and afterwards converting it to PDF document. It runs about 20k of small documents, which compose the whole batch.

Right now I'm getting about 20 docs/sec, but the System is only about 45-55% cpu usage, so something is preventing me to get it to work at full throttle

I'm running in Windows 2012 R2 Standard on an HP Proliant DL385p Gen8 (32GB RAM, 2 x AMD Opteron 6272 each with 16 2.1GHz cores )

All resources are locally stored, so almost no network traffic should be bothering.

I've also tried to write the PDF output documents to a RAMDISK, but there's no improvement at all.

Any ideas of where should I peek to let this process use the whole power of my server?

Thanks!!

PS: Please see attached reference image

[image]

[CPU Usage graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETrV6.png)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, 47% CPU usage would mean 8 of your 16 cores are at full throttle. Is the code threaded correctly?

Comment: I'm actually using a ThreadPoolExecutor (64 thread pool size) to multithread the process. It also seems to me that it's using only 1 CPU, but Java is supposed to span across all available CPUs, am I rigt?

Comment: You should probably look at the Ressource Monitor and make sure your bottleneck is not on your Hard Drive or Network. It seems to me this kind of activity would quickly be blocked by I/O.

Comment: Peek, I've watched over both network and HDD, but they don't show % usage, that's why I've even tried the RAMDISK approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest playing with the number of threads and figuring out a way to test for I/O saturation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the actual issue is that you're fully using one CPU but not the other.

The good news is that you can probably easily multithread your application to use both processors; just set up a task queue and play around with the number of worker threads you have until you achieve 100% usage.

Comment: As everything pointed out to just 1 CPU being used, I decided to create a new WAS profile and fire 2 batches in parallel, as result CPU usage finally jumped over 50% up to about 75%..so somehow either IBM's JVM still uses green threads, or a single ThreadGroup (from a ThreadPoolExecutor) is only bound to a single CPU.