# IBM's JVM still uses green threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, websphere, java-ee-6

Regarding question [Why I'm not using 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358532/why-im-not-using-100), it seems that maybe IBM's JVM (shipped with WAS 8.5) is still using green threads, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't image why it would be using green threads nor does the chart you showed suggest it it.

You have a machine with 32 logical process which are about 50% busy.  This means about 16 native threads being used.

A more likely cause is that the process is locked to one of two sockets and this would explain the about 50% usage.

Comment: Right clicking on the process (java.exe) shows it's bound to "All Processors" :(

Comment: That does not mean that it has threads in a running state on all of them.

Comment: @gvasquez `jps -lvm` shows all processes, `jstack {pid}` gives you the state of all thread and whether they are blocked waiting for a lock for example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey neither jps nor jstack commands are avaible in IBM's JVM :(

Comment: @gvasquez You can use `ps | grep java` to find the process and use `top -H -p {pid}` to show all the threads of a process.

Comment: @PeterLawrey sorry, but no top is available either, as this issue is in Windows :( I'll try to see what happens if I try the same app in a Linux Box

Comment: @gvasquez Windows Task Manager can give you the number of threads.