# Are Java ThreadGroup objects bound to a single CPU?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, threadpool, cpu-usage

I'm using a ThreadPoolExecutor, which is used for a batch process, but a single thread pool on a single JVM just uses 1 of the available server's CPUs. If fire a parallel second JVM with a new thread pool I get the the other CPU to be used.

So I'm wondering, a ThreadPoolExecutor uses a single underlying ThreadGroup for it's "workers", are these threads bound to a single CPU due to to the fact that they belong to a single ThreadGroup? If not, any others ideas?

See related question: [Why I'm not using 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358532/why-im-not-using-100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a ThreadPoolExecutor uses a single underlying ThreadGroup for it's "workers", are these threads bound to a single CPU due to to the fact that they belong to a single ThreadGroup?

No.  All threads in all JVMs are in the same `ThreadGroup` unless you specifically change it.  This in no way changes how the underlying native threads are scheduled so it is not the reason why you do not seem to be using multiple CPUs.

> If not, any others ideas?

My first response is to question whether it actually is not using multiple CPUs.  If you are looking at the CPU usage of the process, it may not be more than 100% because it is blocking on IO.  This doesn't, however, mean that it is *not* using multiple CPUs.  It may be that it is using many CPUs just that none of the tasks submitted to the thread-pool are "CPU bound".  For example, if you run the following application then it should use multiple CPUs and should go above 100% CPU utilization (if you are on a system which measures CPU as a function of number of processors).  If, however, you insert logging calls or reading from network or disk it may be limited by IO and not able to get above 100%.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  long total = 0;
                  while (true) {
                     total++;
                  }
              }
         });
     }
 }
```

> If fire a parallel second JVM with a new thread pool I get the the other CPU to be used.

It may be that on your architecture your JVM is not able to schedule on multiple CPUs.  Certainly most of the common architectures and JVM variants are able to schedule to all available CPUs and multiple cores but maybe you are on an interesting configuration.

Comment: I created a second profile (new JVM) and fired the process in parallel, then I got much more than 50% CPU usage, almost doubling the task/sec rate, so I think I have no IO blocking, but is there any strict way I can assure this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what tasks your threads are doing @gvasquez?

Comment: I think we are confusing things: he has two processors, each of them has 16 cores. So there are 32 cores in total, however Java only manages to saturate one processor. We can't tell you more about that, because we don't see your code. Neither do I know about if the IBM JVM can saturate more than one processor per JVM- Windows seems to be able to do it, as a second process satures all processors.

Comment: Typically JVMs are able to schedule to all CPUs and all cores but that certain does depend on the hardware and the JVM variant in question @ThomasJungblut.  I've added that to my answer.

Comment: @Gray: More details about the tasks: it goes to an ECM repository (IBM CMOD: both database and FS read), then converts the data to PDF, which is written to FS too, but I've tried writing to a RAMDISK to ensure no IO blocking in this part of the process.

Comment: You are going to be bound by the CPU of your database process @gvasquez.  Can you simulate the database lookup and just generate some fake data every time to see what your process does?  The PDF conversion should be all CPU.

Comment: Thanks @Gray I'll try mocking the ECM Read process (DB) to take this part out of the equation

Answer (score 1):

No they are not bound to a CPU.  However, you can control CPU affinity if you want to experiment using the [Java-Thread-Affinity library](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity).